# Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method: Intellij error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I made an abstract class

```
public abstract class AuraSensei {
   abstract boolean has();
}
```

but i'm getting error (see above); need to implement abstract method. thats exactly what I think I did in this code.

```
public class MariaAura extends AuraSensei {
   boolean has() {
      return false;
   }
}
```

is this IDE INTELLIJ IDEA fault or am I just being stupid? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are they in the same package?

Comment: One is X.Data and the other X.Data.Objects.

Comment: You would need to make sure that the class is implemented, a quick restart of IntelliJ might end up fixing your issue if it still persists.

Comment: I restarted it twice. I will restart Linux now. Intellj cant find any methods to implement, when I use Ctrl + I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to be implementing your abstract method in another package, it needs to be `protected` so it's visible to the subclass. Otherwise, it's as if you're declaring a separate method without overriding the abstract one.

This is one reason why you should always mark method overrides with the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: The package structure is indeed the problem, but what exactly do I need to put protected?        protected boolean has() { return false;}
    does not work.

Comment: @Franz-kun `protected` means it's visible to its package and to any subclasses. You have to make them both (at least) `protected`. And please be more specific than "does not work".

Comment: Thanks. It does work, now that I added protected to the main class too.

Comment: You could also make the method's visibility `public`, `protected` is pretty unnecessary unless it's only directly interacting with the superclass (I'm guessing he wants it interacting with the outside program, not just internally).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that makes no sense. Did you forget what `protected` means?

Comment: I honestly did. my bad. I'm sorry.